# SSRS calculating linear trends for groups

Tags: reporting-services, aggregates

Suppose I have a dataset with values like this:

```
Date      A        B        C        D
1/1/2017  0.67     0.87     0.34     0.77
2/1/2017  0.76     0.76     0.55     0.70
3/1/2017  0.83     0.83     0.56     0.67
4/1/2017  0.90     0.79     0.49     0.67
...
```

I need to calculate linear trend for each of the columns. Meaning I need to compare in a group summary whether each value is sequentially larger or smaller than the previous month's value.

I have three outcomes that I need to display:

- The trend is ↑ (each figure is greater than or equal to all previous months.)
- The trend is ↓ (each figure is less than or equal to all previous months.)
- The trend is ↔ (all other situations.)

Using the example dataset, Column A would be ↑, Column D would be ↓, and all other columns would be ↔. I need to be able to track this in a Group summary for each of the columns.

I'd attempted to track this in a rudimentary form using a RunningValue function to populate a "+","-", or "=" to a concatenated string using Custom Code. Where I run into issues with this kludge is that I'm trying to poll these results for multiple columns and it tries to concatenate each calculation to a single string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely not be the best way to do this, but it is the first solution which popped into my head and worked, at least for the dataset I tested. First, the entire expression I used:

```
=Switch(
    Sum(
        IIf(
            Fields!E.Value - Lookup(DateAdd("m", -1, Fields!Date.Value), Fields!Date.Value, Fields!E.Value, "DataSet3") = 0 AND Fields!Date.Value <> Min(Fields!Date.Value),
            1,
            0
        )
    ) = DateDiff("m", Min(Fields!Date.Value), Max(Fields!Date.Value)), "+-",
    Sum(
        IIf(
            Fields!E.Value - Lookup(DateAdd("m", -1, Fields!Date.Value), Fields!Date.Value, Fields!E.Value, "DataSet3") >= 0 AND Fields!Date.Value <> Min(Fields!Date.Value),
            1,
            0
        )
    ) = DateDiff("m", Min(Fields!Date.Value), Max(Fields!Date.Value)), "+",
    Sum(
        IIf(
            Fields!E.Value - Lookup(DateAdd("m", -1, Fields!Date.Value), Fields!Date.Value, Fields!E.Value, "DataSet3") <= 0 AND Fields!Date.Value <> Min(Fields!Date.Value),
            1,
            0
        )
    ) = DateDiff("m", Min(Fields!Date.Value), Max(Fields!Date.Value)), "-",
    true, "+-"
)
```

So essentially what this is: the `Switch` statement is checking if the count of positive or negative differences between months is the same as the number of months minus one (in other words, if the trend is always >= 0 or always <= 0)

We are using the `Sum(IIf(` here as a makeshift `CountIf` since SSRS does not have a CountIf` function.

The first section of the `Switch` is checking if the differences are all = 0, meaning the values did not change at all between months. I included this in the "+-"/"↔" case.

The next section of the `Switch` is checking if the differences are all positive. We get the difference with this part of the expression:

```
Fields!A.Value - Lookup(DateAdd("m", -1, Fields!Date.Value), Fields!Date.Value, Fields!A.Value, "DataSet3")
```

And we are checking if that difference is >= 0. But we also need to make sure to ignore the first month: there is no previous month to compare it.

```
AND Fields!Date.Value <> Min(Fields!Date.Value)
```

We then check if this count equals the number of months minus one:

```
DateDiff("m", Min(Fields!Date.Value, Max(Fields!Date.Value))
```

For the sample dataset given, this will of course return 3 which is what we want. If these two values are equal, then the trend for that column is always >= 0.

The next condition of the switch just checks if the trend is always <= 0, same deal as the first part.

And then if none of the first three conditions are met, we reach the "else" of the switch (`true`), which will indicate that the trend goes back and forth.

Testing with your sample dataset and the expression above, I arrived at the following:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Date   | A   | B   | C   | D   | E   |
|1/1/2017| 0.67| 0.87| 0.34| 0.77| 0.50|
|2/1/2017| 0.76| 0.76| 0.55| 0.70| 0.50|
|3/1/2017| 0.83| 0.83| 0.56| 0.67| 0.50|
|4/1/2017| 0.90| 0.79| 0.49| 0.67| 0.50|
|Trend   | +   | +-  | +-  | -   | +-  |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I like this solution and it's a lot more elegant in recursing through the dataset than what I initially came up with (which was improving my Custom Code kludge to use arrays on a running total.) I think I'm going to need to resolve the "↔" condition as the first hierarchy, as I realize my routine wouldn't account for conditions when the value never changes through the entire reporting period.

Comment: Ah that is a good point, I did not consider that. I will edit my answer to include a check for if the value remains constant to include that in the "↔" case.